# Need help listing the devices on COMM Ports in Python

Tags: python, cmd, serial-port, pyserial

I would like to automatically read all of the devices connected to the computer, so that I can communicate with all of the Keyspans, and none of the other devices. I am using Python, with the PySerial module.

The closest I have gotten is through CMD:

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v

COM1
    desc: Communications Port (COM1)
    hwid: ACPI\PNP0501\2
COM3
    desc: Keyspan USB Serial Port (COM3)
    hwid: KEYSPAN\*USA19HMAP\00_00
COM4
    desc: Keyspan USB Serial Port (COM4)
    hwid: KEYSPAN\*USA19HMAP\01_00
3 ports found
```

I would really like to get this information using a python script instead, something like

```
print(serial.tools.comports)
```

but all that returns is

```
[<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x00000000044022C8>, 
<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x00000000043F8288>, 
<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x00000000043F8388>]
```

and I am not exactly sure what that means. If you have any suggestions I would love to hear them! EDIT: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Before asking this question, did you try reading the documentation for PySerial such as https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html. If not, why don’t you read it now?

Comment: I have read through the documentation quite a bit, but I think the problem is my own understanding of how to implement it. I am on a windows computer so the function works for my system, and it outputs a list of objects as shown here. A better way to ask this question might have been, "How do I read the relevant data from this list of objects?"

Comment: your result shows that `serial.tools.comports` is a list so you can use `for`-loop to display every element separatelly - and then you should use other methods in every item to get more information. Check `print( dir(serial.tools.comports[0]) )` to see methods avaliable for item on list.

Comment: Whoa. That is super cool. I will play around with this for a bit, but I was able to get it to tell me the comm port with `x = serial.tools.listports.comports print(x[0].device)`. Thanks for showing me dir, that is an incredible function to know.

Comment: I got it! using `print(x[1].description)` output `Keyspan USB Serial Port (COM3)`. Should I post it as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result shows that `serial.tools.comports` is a list so you can use `for`-loop to format it or run some functions with every element separatelly.

```
for item in serial.tools.comports:
    print( item )
```

Using `dir(item)` you can see all methods and properties avaliable in this object.

Using  `help(item)` you should see documentation which is inside source code.

If you will know methods then you can use them

```
for item in serial.tools.comports:
    print("Device:", item.device)
    print("Description:", item.desctiption)
```

---

**EDIT:** base on documentation for [ListPortInfo](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html#serial.tools.list_ports.ListPortInfo) you should have

```
for item in serial.tools.comports:
    print( item.name )
    print( item.description )
    print( item.hwid )
    print( item.vid )
    print( item.pid )
    print( item.serial_number )
    print( item.location )
    print( item.manufacturer )
    print( item.product )
    print( item.interface )
```